# Django: How to get latest record?

Tags: python, django

What I want to do is that for a particular Cylinder Id , if cylinder is issued then the user name and the issue date will be displayed in cylinder List ans also if cylinder is returned then the return date will be displayed in cylinder List so for that i used prefetch_related and in template i iterate the issue and return model like this :-

```
{%for cy in cylinder %}
                    <tr bgcolor="#e6f0ff" align="center">
                        
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50"><a style="border-width: 0px" href="{{cy.get_absolute_url}}">{{cy.cylinderId}}<a></td>
               
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.EntryDate}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.gasName}}</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">
                    {{cy.cylinderSize}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">
                    {{cy.Status}}</td>
                    <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{cy.Availability}}</td>

                {% if cy.issue_set.all%}
                
                {% for issue in cy.issue_set.all %}
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{issue.issueDate}}</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{issue.userName}}</td>
               {% endfor %}
                
                {% else %}
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>

                {% endif%}

                 {% if cy.return_set.all%}
                
                {% for return in cy.return_set.all %}
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">{{return.returnDate}}</td>
               
               {% endfor %}
                
                {% else %}
                
                <td align="center" height="10" 
                width="50">-</td>

                {% endif%}
                                
                
                    </tr>

                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>

            {% else %}
```

But another problem is happening that if I reissue the same cylinder/return again the same cylinder Id, so in cylinder list table it is showing all issue and return entries created for that cylinder id but instead i just want to display the latest issue and return entry, for this what I should do?

here is my view:-

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    cylinder=Cylinder.objects.all().prefetch_related().order_by('-EntryDate')
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html',locals())
```

here is models:-

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Cylinder(models.Model):
    stachoice=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty') 
    ]
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','available'), 
    ('Unavailable','unavailable'),
    ('Issued','issued') 
    
    ]
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True,null=False)
    gasName=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cylinderSize=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Status=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=stachoice,default='fill')
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('cylinderDetail',args=[(self.cylinderId)])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinderId)

class Issue(models.Model):
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk: 
            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Available':
                Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))

        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        
    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName) 


class Return(models.Model):
    fill=[
    ('Fill','fill'),
    ('Empty','empty'),
    ('refill','Refill')
    ]

    ava=[
    ('yes','YES'),
    ('no','NO')
    ]
    cylinder=models.ForeignKey('Cylinder',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    availability=models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=ava)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=fill)
    returnDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if not self.pk:

            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Issued':
                
                if self.availability=='YES' or self.availability=='yes':
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Available')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')
                else:
                    Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability='Unavailable')
                    if self.status=='refill' or self.status=='Refill':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Refill')
                    if self.status=='empty' or self.status=='Empty':
                        Cylinder.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Status='Empty')


        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinder)
```

the view  i want:

[image]

Comment: Why is the second item may 4th, 12:00 for a `Cylinder` with id = 100? This does not appear in any of the tables.

Comment: the second item cylinder with **id=100** will only appear in **Issue table** and  **Return table** respectively  not in cylinder table , In **Cylinder table** only the recent entries for cylinder id=100 will be appear i.e. **7may , 15:00**

Comment: but exactly *what* is the supposed output? So `Return` is not the desired result, but another table/model?

Comment: Return and Issue are other models. I am also editing my models. I be very thankful if you can tell me the right way to do this :)

Comment: can you specify the *expected* output for the given data. It is still not entirely clear to me *what* you aim to achieve.

Comment: Cylinder Table is expected output .

Comment: and where does the issue date originates from? Since May 6 14:00 does not appear to be on another table.

Comment: I m very sorry it was a typo , now i have updated new picture with correct data.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the first for this queryset with the [**`.first()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first):

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    cylinder=Cylinder.objects.order_by('-EntryDate').first()
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html', {'cylinder': cylinder})
```

or we can order in *ascending* order, and return the [**`.last()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#last):

```
def cylinderListView(request):
    cylinder=Cylinder.objects.order_by('EntryDate').last()
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html', {'cylinder': cylinder})
```

In that case, you do *not* iterate over `cylinder`, since this is not a *collection* of `Cylinder`s, but a single `Cylinder`.

or if you want the item with a specific id to be the last one, you can work with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

def cylinderListView(request):
    # specific id
    specific_id = 42  # expression for a certain value
    cylinders = Cylinder.objects.prefetch_related().order_by(
        ExpressionWrapper(
            Q(pk=specific_id),
            output_field=BooleanField()
        ).asc(),
        '-EntryDate'
    )
    
    return render(request,'entry/cylinderList.html', {'cylinders': cylinders})
```

In that case it is better to name the variable `cylinders`, since it is a *collection* of zero, one or *more* `Cylinder`s.

Comment: I want to display all cylinder entries but what i want that  the corresponding entry of issue for that particular cylinder id will be the latest one.

Comment: @ShagunRaghav: then you first order based on a condition, see edit.

Comment: I tried to run your suggestion but it is not changing the performance

Comment: @ShagunRaghav: but it will not change performance, it will set the `Cylinder` with the `specified_id` as primary key as the first item in the queryset, that's all. If it was possible to boost performance, then there would be no reason tu use `.all()`, etc.

Comment: what I mean to say that it is not resulting in what i want, sorry if i was not clear with my question so the query i want to run is that ....if a cylinder has two issue entries then the issue entry which is created recently or which is closer to now   will be displayed  with the cylinder entry. For this what should i do

Comment: @ShagunRaghav: exactly *when* are two entries the same?

Comment: @ShagunRaghav: can you please explain with an example _what_ you aim to achieve. Perhaps making a sophisticated query is simply not the way to go, and thus better options are available.

Comment: thanks for your patient :), i have attached a picture in my question, where you can observer that for cylinder id 100 there is two entries in issue table and return table but in cylinder table the entry created recently is displaying , I hope it will help you to understand  :)